# WCF File Not Found when hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, file-io, filesystems

I have a few XML files in my WCF service that are mapped like

```
\\servermain\D$\apps\dataservice\bin\Type\FileName.xml
\\servermain\D$\apps\dataservice\bin\Type\Config\ConfigFile.xml
```

I refer to these files in my program by using

```
.\\Type\\FileName.xml
.\\Type\\Config\\ConfigFile.xml
```

When i run my application through the console as a service it works completely fine... when i deploy it to the IIS server i get an error saying the file can't be found...

Here is a bit of text from my result (My WCF service spits out JSON)

```
"Message":"IO Exception C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\inetsrv","Detail":"File does not exist: .\\Type\\Config\\ConfigFile.xml"
```

I used System.Environment.CurrentDirectory to get the current directory for the error above.

How do i configure it so that my application path is actually

```
\\servermain\D$\apps\dataservice\bin\
```

I would prefer if I wouldn't have to hardcode the actual path of the file, because developers would be running this service through their local machines as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would prefer if I wouldn't have to hardcode the actual path of the file, because developers would be running this service through their local machines as well.

That's what you are doing right now. A possible way to resolve this hardcoded paths is pretty easy:
Every WCF service comes with a config file. You can easily add the [appSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) element to your config and specify absolute or relative paths to any additional file.

E.g. for executing the console:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConfigFile" value=".\\Type\\Config\\ConfigFile.xml" />
</appSettings>
```

And instead for the IIS hosted config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConfigFile" value="\\servermain\D$\apps\dataservice\bin\Type\Config\ConfigFile.xml" />
</appSettings>
```

You can then access those values via the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings` class.

**UPDATE:**
The `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings` is marked as obsolete. Instead, the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` or `System.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager` should be used.